# wrong encoding When adding audio file to android studio

Tags: android-studio-2.2

I add audio file .mp3 to raw folder in android studio and an error with these details:

**File was loaded in the wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'**

Comment: please show me to solve this problem as soon as you can with my thanks

Comment: It's probably just got a .txt extension and thinks the .mp3 file is UTF-8. It might be that the mp3 has some UTF-8 comments that need to be stripped out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the image - just **remove the *.mp3**  from the text files by clicking on **'-'** icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are pasting .mp3 file then remove "."(dot),upperlettters(capitals) and other symbols only use small(a to z) and no's(1 to 9) only